# Terms in GP series finding trigonometry summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Let ${a_r}\left( {{a_r} > 0\forall r \in N} \right)$ be the $r^{th}$ term of a GP such that $\sqrt {{a_1}.{a_3}.{a_5}.{a_7}}  = {\left( {18{a_1} + {a_1}{r^2}} \right)^2}$ and $\sum\limits_{r = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{a_r}}} = \frac{3}{4}} $. The value of $\sum\limits_{r = 1}^{10} {\tan \left( {{{\sin }^{ - 1}}\left( {\frac{{{a_{r + 1}}}}{{\sqrt {{a_r}^2 + {a_{r + 1}}^2} }}} \right)} \right)} $=_____

My approach is as follow

Let $r\in N$

${a_1} = {a_1};{a_3} = {a_1}{r^2};{a_5} = {a_1}{r^4};{a_7} = {a_1}{r^6}$

$\sqrt {{a_1}^4.{r^{12}}}  = {\left( {18{a_1} + {a_1}{r^2}} \right)^2}$

${a_1}^2{r^6} = {a_1}^2{\left( {18 + {r^2}} \right)^2} \Rightarrow {r^6} = {\left( {18 + {r^2}} \right)^2}$

${r^6} = 324 + 36{r^2} + {r^4} \Rightarrow {r^6} - {r^4} - 36{r^2} - 324 = 0$

How do I proceed from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:$$r^6={(18+r^2)}^2$$ $$r^3=18+r^2,r^3=-18-r^2$$
$$r^3=18+r^2\Rightarrow r^2(r-1)=(3)3(2)\Rightarrow \boxed{r=3}$$ Also $r^3=-18-r^2\Rightarrow r^2(r+1)=(-3)(-3)(-3+1)\Rightarrow r=-3$  hence rejected

Using $r=3$ can you do the rest?